# Convert CRC calculation from C# to C

Tags: c#, c, pic, crc

I am currently working on a serial monitor, to ensure some data integrity I am trying to implement a CRC8 checksum, below is the calculation i do on any messages before i send them.

```
public byte Checksum(params byte[] val)
{
    if (val == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("val");
    byte c = 0;
    foreach (byte b in val)
    {
        c = table[c ^ b];
    }
    return c;
}
```

I generate a table using 0xD8:

```
public byte[] GenerateTable(CRC8_POLY polynomial)
{
    byte[] csTable = new byte[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        int curr = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        {
            if ((curr & 0x80) != 0)
            {
            curr = (curr << 1) ^ (int)polynomial;
            }
            else
            {
                curr <<= 1;
            }
        }
        csTable[i] = (byte)curr;
    }
    return csTable;
}
```

This is a code i have used for testing the setup:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProtoFrame rxFrame = new ProtoFrame();
    if (cboParam.Text == "test")
    {
        rxFrame.Start = 0x73;
        rxFrame.Size = 9;
        rxFrame.Command = 01;
        rxFrame.Unused = 0;
        rxFrame.ParamId = 0x0100;
        rxFrame.Param = 8000;
    }

    byte[] rxBuffer = getBytes(rxFrame); //call to byte array formatter
    rxBuffer[rxBuffer.Length-1] = Checksum(rxBuffer); //append crc at end of array
    ComPort.Write(rxBuffer, 0, rxBuffer.Length);
}
static byte[] getBytes(object str) //input struct
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str) + 1;
    byte[] arr = new byte[size];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    return arr;
}
```

As far as i know this code work as intendended, and im using the table generator to implement a hardcoded table in my microcontroller, to speed up the process.
  What i dont quite get is how i implement a function to calculate the CRC in a similar way as i do here.
  Any help or guides in the right direction is aprreciated.
  So far i have come up with this function:

```
uint8_t crc8(uint8_t *crc)
{
    uint8_t crcVal;
    int m;
    for (m = 0; m < PacketSize ;m++ )startbyte
    {
        *crc = crc8_table[(*crc) ^ m];
        *crc &= 0xFF;        
    }
}
```

where table is:

```
uint8_t crc8_table[256] = {0,24,48,40,96,120,80,72,192,216,240,232,160,184,144,136,88,64,104,112,56,32,8,16,
                    152,128,168,176,248,224,200,208,176,168,128,152,208,200,224,248,112,104,64,88,16,8,
                    32,56,232,240,216,192,136,144,184,160,40,48,24,0,72,80,120,96,184,160,136,144,216,
                    192,232,240,120,96,72,80,24,0,40,48,224,248,208,200,128,152,176,168,32,56,16,8,64,
                    88,112,104,8,16,56,32,104,112,88,64,200,208,248,224,168,176,152,128,80,72,96,120,48,
                    40,0,24,144,136,160,184,240,232,192,216,168,176,152,128,200,208,248,224,104,112,88,
                    64,8,16,56,32,240,232,192,216,144,136,160,184,48,40,0,24,80,72,96,120,24,0,40,48,120,
                    96,72,80,216,192,232,240,184,160,136,144,64,88,112,104,32,56,16,8,128,152,176,168,224,
                    248,208,200,16,8,32,56,112,104,64,88,208,200,224,248,176,168,128,152,72,80,120,96,40,
                    48,24,0,136,144,184,160,232,240,216,192,160,184,144,136,192,216,240,232,96,120,80,72,
                    0,24,48,40,248,224,200,208,152,128,168,176,56,32,8,16,88,64,104,112
                    };
```

and PacketSize is found from rxFrame.Size

Comment: You should post some efforts on translation before to ask something here. This is not a code-for-me service.

Comment: agreed, i just thought it would be confusing to mix it all up. edited to include what i have regarding calculating crc

Comment: Issues, first 0xD8 is not a valid polynomial for a left shifting CRC8, second, the table is using 0x18 not 0xD8: note that table[1] = 24 == 0x18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you simply need to port your C# function to C

```
public byte Checksum(params byte[] val)
{
    if (val == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("val");
    byte c = 0;
    foreach (byte b in val)
    {
        c = table[c ^ b];
    }
    return c;
}
```

**I**. there are no exceptions in C. Use return value to indicate errors and add an argument that you'll use as a return value. It's up to you to decide whether to pass a message length as a parameter or leave it at the global scope:

```
int checksum(uint8_t const *msg, size_t msglen, uint8_t *result)
```

**II**. `foreach` loop is converted to `for` loop, where `i` is index and `msg[i]` is the `b` from the `foreach`:

```
int checksum(uint8_t const *msg, size_t msglen, uint8_t *result)
{
    if (msg == NULL || msglen == 0)
        return 0;

    uint8_t crc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < msglen; i++)
    {
        crc = table[crc ^ msg[i]];
    }
```

**III**. Store the result and return a success code:

```
int checksum(uint8_t const *msg, size_t msglen, uint8_t *result)
{
    if (msg == NULL || msglen == 0)
        return 0;

    uint8_t crc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < msglen; i++)
    {
        crc = table[crc ^ msg[i]];
    }

    *result = crc;
    return 1;
}
```

**IV**. Usage:

```
uint8_t crc;
if (!checksum(message, PacketSize, &crc))
    report_error();
```

Comment: Nice. But minor nitpicks: 1. `msg` should be `uint8_t const *` since it's not modified. 2. I would avoid array syntax when not dealing with arrays `result[0] = crc; -> *result = crc;`. Optional nitpick: `result` is not strictly necessary, you could also use negative return values for error codes, and return `0-255` for result.

Comment: @user694733 `const` and array notation: agreed. Error codes: nice trick actually!

Comment: what do i pass as the result parameter? since the crc value is appended to the msg array. thx for clarifying everything, it helps me understand the reasoning behind the extra code

Comment: @Claudi As you see in part IV, I create a variable `crc` and pass `&crc` to function in order to have result written in `crc` variable. `&crc` means `address of crc in memory`. It's a rough equivalent of saying "I have a `crc` variable at 0x0ea134c, please put the result there". Pointers and memory addresses are important concepts in C so I'd suggest you to read about it.

Comment: I wish I could have you at my side every time i have questions, as you explain it exactly to my understanding. I have a rough equivalent implemented now, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the C# code should be:

```
uint8_t crc8(uint8_t const *crc, size_t size)
{
    unit8_t c = 0;
    size_t  m;
    for (m = 0; m < size; m++ )
    {
        c = crc8_table[c ^ *crc];
        crc++;
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: I have issues with: 1. `crc` is poorly named. 2. It should have type `uint8_t const *`. 3. `PacketSize` should be argument.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use pointers, convert to arrays

```
        public static byte crc8(byte[] crc)
         {
             byte crcVal;
             int m;
             for (m = 0; m < PacketSize; m++)
             {
                 crc[m] = crc8_table[crc[m] ^ m];
                 crc[m] &= 0xFF;
             }
             return crcVal;
         }
```

Comment: OP asked for C code, not C#. Also, this won't calculate the crc correctly.